# How to get selected value from combo box on form submit in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

**The code to populate combo box from database**

```
<td>Item Name:</td>
    <td><select name="items">
        <option value="0" selected="selected"> Choose</option>
        <?php
         while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
         {
            $category = $row["ItemName"];
            echo "$category";
        ?>
        <option value= <?php $category ?> > <?php echo  $category ?> </option>
        <?php
      }?>
      </select></td>
```

**Code for submit**

```
<td><input type="submit" name="newItem" value="New Item"/></td>
```

**PHP code is:**

```
 <?php
    if(isset($_POST['newItem']))
    {
    $item=$_POST['items'];
    $sel=mysql_query("select ItemID from itemmaster where ItemName='$item'");
    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($sel))
    {
               //code
        }
```

Comment: Value should be inside quotes `<option value= "<?php $category ?> "> <?php echo  $category ?> </option>`

Comment: **Danger**: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Comment: You already have code in the question to get the value from your select element. What is the problem?

Comment: A combobox is a UI control that is a combination (hence the name) of a drop down menu (which is what you get with a select in HTML) and a text input (an input of type text). HTML doesn't have any native controls that are represented as comboboxes. If you want one then you would have to build it with a pile of JavaScript. You have "a select element".

Comment: What has a combo-box got to do with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

Value should be inside quotes

change:

```
<option value= <?php $category ?> > <?php echo  $category ?> </option>
```

to

```
<option value= "<?php $category ?> "> <?php echo $category ?> </option>
```